# medium-editor.directive.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: typescript, angular5, medium-editor

Not able to use angular-medium-editor library in Angular 5

Packages installed:

```
"angular-medium-editor": "^4.0.0-alpha",
"angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"typescript": "~2.5.3"
```

During `ng serve` command I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-medium-editor/medium-editor.directive.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/K2A/GIT/traveldiary/webapp/node_modules/angular-medium-editor/medium-editor.directive.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format 
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/webapp/node_modules//src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:656:23)
at plugin.done.then (/node_modules//src/loader.js:467:39)
at 
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
@ ./src/app/pages/pages.module.ts 18:32-88
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

How to fix this issue and use the library?

Answer (score 0):

#### The error message

The error message oocurs because the library includes TypeScript files. The [Angular Package Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/edit) requires a properly packaged library to not include any TypeScript files to prevent issues with different versions of TypeScript at compilation time.

#### The actual problem

If you check out [the GitHub site](https://github.com/thijsw/angular-medium-editor) of `angular-medium-editor` you'll see it is an AngularJS plugin which won't work for any version of Angular.

It seems someone has made an Angular port of it (angular2-medium-editor), see [GitHub](https://github.com/codiak/angular2-medium-editor).